# Adding a number on top of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing an issue, adding a text from my CSS file. I tried the keyword content, but that doesn't help it seems.

So what i want to do is, when the user clicks on the image i want to add numbers (in an incremental order). For example. Click 1 should say `1` (Next to the white box), and then click `2` etc.

I added a variable called `counter` and initialised it to `0`. So, when the user clicks the `counter` will increase by `1`. However, i think the attribute `content` alone will be enough as i am suppose to give colour to the text other than white (which is the colour of the box).

[jsfiddle as follows](http://jsfiddle.net/95vczfve/9/):

The above code is what i want to edit. However, i created another JSfiddle, to do a sample. [Here is the code for it](http://jsfiddle.net/jt57p094/).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content - if you are talking about this, then you have to use it with ::before/after pseudoselectors. Also take a look at css4 attr function (like content: attr(data-index); )

Answer (score 3):

Just put the number inside the div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var count = 0;

    $(document).click(function (ev) {        
        $("body").append(            
            $('<div>' + ++count + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: ev.pageY + 'px',
                left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                width: '40px',
                height: '40px',
                background: '#fff'
            })              
        );               
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert `var counter = 0;` at the start of the js file to initialize the variable, than in the click function insert `counter++;` to increment the counter in every click; in body append function change `"<div></div>"` in `'<div>' + counter + '</div>'`.

So your code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var counter = 0;

    $(document).click(function (ev) {   
        counter++;
        $("body").append(            
            $('<div>' + counter + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',

                top: ev.pageY + 'px',
                left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                width: '40px',
                height: '40px',
                background: '#fff'

            })              
        );               
    });

});
```